# HTML5/Javascript: Reset Game Screen

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working on an html5 game, which is basically complete. However, I have created a game over screen that says 'press space to restart', but don't know how to actually restart the game. [Here is a link](http://www.pasteall.org/42571/javascript) to my code.

In line 200 I wrote this:

```
if(keys[32]){
    //
}
```

I have that statement, but I don't what to write to restart the game. I'd appreciate anyone's help with this. 
Thanks

Comment: Are you expecting us to code your game for you? You either need to just reload the page or code in a system to allow you to restart the game.

Comment: I didn't really ask you to write my game for me, I just wanted to know how to restart the game

Comment: You need a function to restart your game. Do you have a function to restart it? If so just call it. Otherwise you need to make one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just reload the page with

```
location.reload();
```

Comment: Alternatively, you could consider writing your game using a state machine. 

i.e. `var gameState = "startScreen"`, `if(gameState=="startScreen") { // show the start Screen } else if (gameState=="gameInProgress") { // game code goes here } else if (gameState=="endScreen") { // show endscreen }` 

You want to have code which changes the state, for example, if someone clicks the 'play again' button on the endscreen, clear the variables and then change the state to gameInProgress

Answer (score 1):

Whenever I want to restart things, I generally call the same initialize function I use to begin them.  You can also hold onto data like this.

```
var foo;
var bar;
var highScore;

initialize(firstTime)
{   
    foo = 42;  bar = 17; 
    if(firstTime){  highScore = 0;  }
}


onGameover()
{
   if(current score > highScore)  {  highScore = current score;  }
   if(person presses space)  {  initialize();  }  //don't actually check for keypress in this function
}
```

Comment: I wasn't using an initialize function, just creating variables and objects. I tried putting all that in a function called 'init', and then called init before the update() function. However, where it references 'player' in the update it says 'player is not defined'

Comment: You should create all your variables and objects before initializing their data, if you want to do it this way.

Comment: so create them, but set them to 0, or don't give them a value

Comment: before being initialized, all your variables should be place holders that exist outside of the current game.  Your basically telling the computer to make room for everything, and keep it until the user leaves the page.  Think of checkers.  All the pieces are there before the game starts, but not until you initialize the game do they have a place on the board.  When you restart, you re-initialize their places.

Comment: that makes a lot of sense. thanks for all your help thumbz! :)